# Creating 3D grid map for amcl

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, visualization, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am doing a known mapping by using amcl, and I wish to improve my map by making it into 3d and view it inside rviz.

Here's my map image. (in .pgm)

[image: image description]

Is there any software in ubuntu that can draw it in 3D?
Image file need to be compatible with yaml file in order to run map_server to be used by amcl.
I am using fuerte.

Thank you so much.

**Post update**

This is a 3D map I draw by using google SketchUp on window. I have exported it into Collada file.

How do I visualize it in rviz with respect to the /map frame?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122581/creating-3d-grid-map-for-amcl/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2014-01-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure there is anything like this readily available. What you could do (or what is the first quick way of doing it that comes to my mind ;) ) is write a small node that subscribes to your map and outputs a [MarkerArray](http://docs.ros.org/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/MarkerArray.html) with a [CubeList](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Cube_List_.28CUBE_LIST.3D6.29) of all areas in the map that are occupied, so you have one scaled cube per occupied grid cell.

/edit: As you already have a 3D object representation of your environment, things are much easier. I recommend making your COLLADA file part of a ROS package and then following the instructions for publishing your mesh as a Marker [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Mesh_Resource_.28MESH_RESOURCE.3D10.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2014-01-27**:
I have exported a .dae file from google SketchUp 8, how do I make use of urdf to visualize it on rviz?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-01-29**:
See updated answer.